# Azure Function Initializing worker process failed in Java

Tags: java, azure-functions

I see lots of threads on the error: `Initializing worker process failed`. Most of the threads mentioned that Microsoft had defects and this is the [tracking id](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/434), but I hardly see the effective solutions. I have spent more than a day trying to figure it out, and then finally decided to reach out to our beautiful Java community. This might look a duplicate, but it's still worth mentioning that I followed the following URL on my office laptop (Windows 10) and my personal laptop (Windows 11).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-java?tabs=bash%2Cazure-cli%2Cbrowser

It runs well on my Windows 10 machine, but it's continuously getting the following error on my personal laptop. I thought it could be some compatibility issue on Windows 11. With this theory in mind, I tried to follow the same tutorial on my other personal laptop with Windows 10, and I'm seeing the same issue there that I see on Windows 11.

```
*info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
        Executing endpoint 'gRPC - 
/AzureFunctionsRpcMessages.FunctionRpc/EventStream'
[2021-11-17T19:28:26.889Z] Initializing worker process failed
[2021-11-17T19:28:26.892Z] The operation has timed out.
[2021-11-17T19:28:26.896Z] Failed to start language worker process for runtime: (null). workerId:517f5d97-29f1-43c5-a13c-746e666205c8
[2021-11-17T19:28:27.820Z] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5105
[2021-11-17T19:28:27.925Z] Removing errored webhost language worker channel for runtime: java workerId:517f5d97-29f1-43c5-a13c-746e666205c8
[2021-11-17T19:28:27.927Z] System.Private.CoreLib: The operation has timed out.
```

Functions:

```
HttpExample: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpExample
For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2021-11-17T19:28:28.173Z] ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
[2021-11-17T19:28:28.174Z] ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
[2021-11-17T19:28:28.175Z] JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
[2021-11-17T19:28:28.302Z] ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
[2021-11-17T19:28:28.304Z] ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
[2021-11-17T19:28:28.305Z] JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
[2021-11-17T19:29:27.953Z] Starting worker process failed
[2021-11-17T19:29:27.959Z] The operation has timed out.*
```

I tried to follow many different suggestions but all failed in the last 2 days. I even tried the following configuration as suggested in one of the threads, but had no luck.

```
*{
"IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": **"UseDevelopmentStorage=true"**,
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java"
  }
}*
```

Answer (score 0):

We have followed same [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-java?tabs=cmd%2Cazure-cli%2Cbrowser) steps, tried reproing in our local environment by creating a Http Trigger function with java as runtime.

We are able to run the function in our local environment without any issues.

**Note**: Our local environment is running with Windows 11 operating system, Azure functions core tools V3.0.3904,jdk version 1.8.0_302.

Here is the sample output screenshot for reference:

[image]

The git hub issue [Worker Process startup timeout](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/434) that  you are referring to is related to the azure functions which are running with dotnet isolated not for java runtime.

We tried checking out the git hub related to [azure functions for java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues?q=is%3Aopen%20is%3AInitializing%20%20worker%20process%20failed) whether this is an open issue but we didn't found any.

If you still faces the issue we would suggest you to open a discussion over [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/products/) or please create a technical support ticket by following the [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) where technical support team would help you in troubleshooting the issue from platform end.

Comment: After seeing your screenshot I have downgraded func-cli to 3.0.3904 from 4.0.3971 and tried again. Stuck in the same problem. I literally executed 4 commands (as described in your official website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-java?tabs=bash%2Cazure-cli%2Cbrowser) without any changes.
1. mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.microsoft.azure -DarchetypeArtifactId=azure-functions-archetype -DjavaVersion=8

2. cd fabrikam-functions

3. mvn clean package

4. mvn azure-functions:run

Please continue reading my next comment

Comment: My environment has
java version "1.8.0_311"
func --version: 3.0.3904
Apache Maven 3.6.3
azure-cli 2.30.0

I guess we need to know why below error comes:
Executing endpoint 'gRPC - /AzureFunctionsRpcMessages.FunctionRpc/EventStream'
[2021-11-30T04:19:29.499Z] Initializing worker process failed
[2021-11-30T04:19:29.501Z] The operation has timed out.

Comment: Tried many different ways on my Windows 11 laptop with no positive output. Finally, thought of deploying azure function on Docker to unblock myself from this deadlock and this link helped me: https://medium.com/swlh/azure-functions-docker-java-135c827593e9

Comment: @AshishKumarMondal did you managed to solve the problem in some way? We're experiencing the same behaviour

Comment: Hi @Reste85, as I mentioned, I was using docker to unblock myself.